# How to use django.contrib.humanize in a model

Tags: python, django, humanize

I would like to use the `django.contrib.humanize` outside of a template, actually inside a model to humanize some dates in some text messages.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `import`ing them directly? What happened?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. I just found how to do it.

Answer (score 10):

You can import the functions in the model:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturalday
natural_day = naturalday(value)
```